# How do I deploy Activiti to Tomcat to use an MSSQL database and update the schema on startup?

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, activiti, mssql-jdbc

I am attempting to host an Activiti database in MSSQL 2012 via the MS JDBC sqljdbc4.jar driver.  I have setup Activiti 5.14 in JBoss, got fed up, and am starting over with 5.15.1 in Tomcat 7.  So upon deployment and start up of the activiti-explorer.war, it is attempting to upgrade the database schema of my 5.14 activiti database hosted in MS SQL.

The upgrade fails, and the errors show up in the catalina.out log file of the Tomcat server:

```
05:10:38,962 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession  - upgrading activiti engine schema from 5.14 to 5.15.1
05:10:38,962 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession  - Upgrade needed: 514 -> 515. Looking for schema update resource for component 'engine'
05:10:38,963 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession  - performing upgrade on engine with resource org/activiti/db/upgrade/activiti.mssql.upgradestep.514.to.515.engine.sql
05:10:38,977 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession  - problem during schema upgrade, statement alter table ACT_RU_TASK 
add CATEGORY_ nvarchar(255)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot find the object "ACT_RU_TASK" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
```

Logging in to the database, I see the `ACT_RU_TASK` table.

What MS SQL permissions does the Activiti database user need in order to perform an in-process database upgrade?  Or, how can I get the Activiti Explorer war to perform the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out, in case anyone needs to know the specific MS SQL details...

The MS SQL database user seems to get along just fine with `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` membership in the Activiti database, if you have run the database create DDL scripts manually ahead of starting the Activiti engine for the first time.

Once the engine (apparently in the activity-engine.jar dependency of activiti-explorer.war) decides you need a database schema upgrade, and it has been configured to attempt such a change, the database user will need `db_ddladmin` membership in the database to perform the alterations.  (Apply base of palm to forehead).

Maybe there is a way to limit the privilege further, but it seems this is better than db_owner.  For production use, and considering zero-downtime change procedure requirements, I'll probably be turning the auto-upgrade feature off.